# Expect Rsync with Double quotes

Tags: shell-script, ssh, rsync, expect

Below is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout -1
spawn rsync -arvz -e 'ssh -p 1690' --protect-args --progress /home/pappu/ 'backup@xx.xx.xx.xx:/volume1/56 - Backup Server/pappu'
expect "password:"
send "******/r"
expect eof
```

script has `+x` permission, and I'm executing it as below:

`~]# ./rsync-backup.sh`

It gives me below output:

```
spawn rsync -arvz -e 'ssh -p 1690' --protect-args --progress /home/pappu/ 'backup@xx.xx.xx.xx:/volume1/56 - Backup Server/pappu'
Unexpected remote arg: 'backup@xx.xx.xx.xx:/volume1/56
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1201) [sender=3.0.6]
send: spawn id exp4 not open
      while executing
"send xxxxxx/r"
      (file "./rsync-backup.sh" line 5)
```

I tried adding double quotes in remote path of rsync, also tried adding slash with single and double quote. (It just changes the error message).

Comment: Any reason why you can't use `ssh` certificate-based authentication, and avoid the need for a password entirely? You could then also dispense with `expect`.

Comment: Did you mean `xxxxxx\r` by any chance?

Comment: @steeldriver : thanks, I mis typed while typing/formatting here in questions

Comment: @roaima, user `backup@xx.xx.xx.xx` doesn't have a home directory, I'm not aware with ssh key without home directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`expect` is written in the `tcl` language, so strings containing whitespace must be quoted with double-quotes `"` not single quotes `'`. So replace your spawn line with

```
spawn rsync -arvz -e "ssh -p 1690" --protect-args --progress /home/pappu/ "backup@xx.xx.xx.xx:/volume1/56 - Backup Server/pappu"
```

Also, as mentioned by @steeldriver, a carriage-return is written `\r`, so you probably want

```
send "******\r"
```

Comment: Thank you @meuh, It is working now, I'll read more about tcl so not stuck on silly things, thanks again for your help